# Override stepUp and stepDown

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any possibility to override html5  stepUp and stepDown behaviour? I don't want to create new buttons, I would like to use controls provided by the input. I've been trying to override them this way:

```
document.getElementById("elemId").stepUp = function() { }
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would recommend that instead of overriding you watch the change event and then do whatever you want.*

That being said, there are two ways in which you can override that behavior. Suppose the following html

```
<input id="num" type="number" value="0" step="1" min="0" max="100"/>
```

Let's get a reference to the number input:

```
// Access the spinner
var spinner = document.getElementById("num");
```

Now if you want to override ALL `stepUp()` functions, you can use the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) Object:

```
// Override all spinner's setup functions
HTMLInputElement.prototype.stepUp = function(num){
    console.log('All overridden: Stepping up '+num);
};
```

Although you can also override only that input's `stepUp()` function:

```
// Override only that spinner's stepUp function
spinner.stepUp = function(num){
   console.log('Stepping up '+num);
};
```

To see an example of this in action open [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59y11b77/).

Comment: Neither Chrome nor Firefox trigger the overridden `stepUp` function when pressing the up or down buttons (or using the up and down keys) for me.